# Creating a change password form in Visual Basic. How to update the SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating a login register with edit information. I'm stuck with the change password form.

Here's what I got - totally lost it, no errors but crashes when tested highlights my reader command

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim sql As String = "Select Username, Password From tblLog Where Username = @Username"
    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = My.Forms.formEdit.tbUser.Text

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    Dim rd As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Try
        If rd.Read = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password")
            tbOldPass.Clear()
            tbNewPass.Clear()
            tbConPass.Clear()
        ElseIf tbConPass.Text <> tbNewPass.Text Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password does not match")
            tbOldPass.Clear()
            tbNewPass.Clear()
            tbConPass.Clear()
        Else
            Dim sqry As String = "Update tblLog Set Password = @Password" &
                "Where Username = @Username And Password = @OldPassword"
            rd.Close()
            Dim scmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqry, con)

            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tbNewPass.Text)
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", My.Forms.formEdit.tbUser.Text)
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldPassword", tbOldPass.Text)
            scmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Information Updated")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Edited: Changed the code a bit, it doesn't crash anymore but my database doesn't get updated

```
        Dim sql As String = "Select Username, Password From tblLog Where Username = @Username And Password = @Password"
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = My.Forms.formEdit.tbPass.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = My.Forms.formEdit.tbUser.Text
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    Try
        If tbOldPass.Text <> My.Forms.formEdit.tbPass.Text = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password")
            tbOldPass.Clear()
            tbNewPass.Clear()
            tbConPass.Clear()
        ElseIf tbConPass.Text <> tbNewPass.Text Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password does not match")
            tbOldPass.Clear()
            tbNewPass.Clear()
            tbConPass.Clear()
        Else
            Dim sqry As String = "Update tblLog Set [Password] = @Pss Where Username = @Use And Password = @OldPassword"
            Dim scmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqry, con)

            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pss", tbNewPass.Text)
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Use", My.Forms.formEdit.tbUser.Text)
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldPassword", My.Forms.formEdit.tbPass.Text)

            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            scmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Information Updated")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: what error do you get ? where does error occur ?

Comment: it doesnt have error in the code but when i run it and click the button it crashes. error on the cmd.executereader when it crashes

Comment: Storing passwords as plain-text is pretty risky.

Comment: Yes sir, i will try to hash it after i get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking my code a bit I realized that I was closing the form where the value of my parameters were taken. So I tried to just hide the form not close it, then it worked. Sorry for the troubles.

Edit:
Should I delete this question or just leave it? I can't select my own answer as the correct for 2 more days

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding space before where in query:

```
Dim sqry As String = "Update tblLog Set Password = @Password" &
                "  Where Username = @Username And Password = @OldPassword"
```

Comment: It still generates an error on the Declaration of the datareader line

Comment: provide more details regarding exception, you can find option to view details while debugging